# I am not able to create grok pattern for activamq logs in logstash

Tags: logstash, activemq-classic, logstash-grok

I am not able to create grok pattern for activemq logs :

```
2018-04-03 20:01:17,960 | INFO  | PListStore:[/data/dccm/activeMQ/apache-activemq-5.15.3/data/localhost/tmp_storage] stopped | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | Thread-24
```

I have tried this pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \s*\|\s*%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} | %{DATA: data}
\: *\[ %{UNIXPATH:folder} \] stopped * \| %{JAVACLASS:class} \| %{WORD:tread}
```

I can get timestamp and loglevel. I have used this debugger: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 4):

The best way to build grok patterns is to start at the left side and work your way incrementally to the right until you've finished.  Debugging a "completed" pattern is the opposite - take stuff off until it starts working.

In your case, even this shorter pattern doesn't match:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \s*\|\s*%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} | %{DATA:data}:
```

Can you see it easier now?  Yup, you didn't escape the pipe character before `data`.

Once you fix that, you can keep adding pieces back in, until you discover that `folder` is not matched.  This is because you have a single space in the pattern just inside the brackets (on both sides).

Lather, rinse, repeat.